# Getting concurrently scripts to complete

Tags: angular-cli, e2e-testing, npm-scripts

I am trying to create a script to run an end-to-end testing suite. I am currently using concurrently and the angular cli, like so:

```json
"e2e": "concurrently \"ng e2e --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\" \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server\"",
```

It runs fine, but my issue is that obviously whilst the `ng e2e` command completes, my backend server does not. Is there any way to get the whole command to finish when the tests are complete?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it! Concurrently has already thought of this and helpfully implemented the following switches `--kill-others --success first`.

`--kill-others` means "if one command completes, kill the other and `--success first` means "if the first command is successful return a success code for the whole concurrently command.

Comment: Thanks! Tried both separately and didn't work. Wasn't until I stumbled upon this gem until got it working!

Comment: Note also, the more concise: `-k -s first`

Comment: Yep, it was not obvious from the documentation that they need to be used together. Thanks!